Mongoose, update values in array of objects - node.js
VolSchema =  mongoose.Schema({
    reference : { type : String , unique : true , required : true } , 
    open  : Boolean , 
    close  :  Boolean , 
    dateDepart :  Date  ,  
    Depart :{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Gare' },  
    Arrivee : { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Gare' }, 
    inStation : Boolean, 
    inRoute : Boolean , 
    tempsfixvalue : Boolean ,
    relatedTickets : {
        type: [{roomId : String,  id : String , passenger : String , quantite : Number , price :        mongoose.Decimal128 ,   confirmer : Boolean }],
        default : []
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
})

example :
 Vol = {
   ...... , 
   relatedTickets  : [
        {roomId : "123" , id : 1 , passenger : "Tayeb"  ,  quantite : 2 , price : 12.00 , confirmer : false},
         {roomId : "1223" , id : 2 , passenger : "Omar"  ,  quantite : 1 , price : 12.00 , confirmer : true},
   ]
}

I want to  update confirmer   of  first relatedTickets to  true
I want the ansure of my queston

Have you tried array filters?

Update the array by its position as below.
// single document update
t.updateOne({_id: new ObjectId('66470d24f60b6d3e37b8289b')},{$set:{"relatedTickets.0.confirmer":true}});

// multiple documents update
t.updateMany({},{$set:{"relatedTickets.0.confirmer":true}});

For details, please see the action below.
use test
t = db.test

// single document update
test> t.find();
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId('66470d24f60b6d3e37b8289b'),
    relatedTickets: [
      { roomId: '123', confirmer: false },
      { roomId: '1223', confirmer: false }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId('66470d29f60b6d3e37b8289c'),
    relatedTickets: [
      { roomId: '123X', confirmer: false },
      { roomId: '1223Y', confirmer: false }
    ]
  }
]

t.updateOne({_id: new ObjectId('66470d24f60b6d3e37b8289b')},{$set:{"relatedTickets.0.confirmer":true}});

test> t.find();
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId('66470d24f60b6d3e37b8289b'),
    relatedTickets: [
      { roomId: '123', confirmer: true },
      { roomId: '1223', confirmer: false }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId('66470d29f60b6d3e37b8289c'),
    relatedTickets: [
      { roomId: '123X', confirmer: false },
      { roomId: '1223Y', confirmer: false }
    ]
  }
]

// multiple documents update
test> t.find();
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId('66470df0f60b6d3e37b8289d'),
    relatedTickets: [
      { roomId: '123', confirmer: false },
      { roomId: '1223', confirmer: false }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId('66470df3f60b6d3e37b8289e'),
    relatedTickets: [
      { roomId: '123X', confirmer: false },
      { roomId: '1223Y', confirmer: false }
    ]
  }
]

t.updateMany({},{$set:{"relatedTickets.0.confirmer":true}});

test> t.find();
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId('66470df0f60b6d3e37b8289d'),
    relatedTickets: [
      { roomId: '123', confirmer: true },
      { roomId: '1223', confirmer: false }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId('66470df3f60b6d3e37b8289e'),
    relatedTickets: [
      { roomId: '123X', confirmer: true },
      { roomId: '1223Y', confirmer: false }
    ]
  }
]

